# How to get the coordinates in the new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

You used to be able to right-click and drop a lat-lon marker on a point to get its coordinates:

[image: lat lon marker]

How do you get the latitude & longitude in the new Google Maps?

[image: no lat lon marker]

**Update:** just got an email from Google today with this announcement:

[image: Get coordinates easier]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can once again get the latitude/longitude for any arbitrary point on the map by right-clicking (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click) and choosing "What's here?"

[image: screen shot from Google]

[[source: +GoogleMaps](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleMaps/posts/jUgY5zNU8NZ)]

Comment: Yup, they've updated their app again. This is quite convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

LEFT-click on the place that you want coordinates for.

Notice that there is a small circle which radiates at that place, or the nearest on-street place.

In the top left of the map, a small display box appears, showing the address and lat/long coordinates:

[image]

- You can copy / paste these as text.
- They are also a hyperlink:   if you click on them, then the map
  centers at that place, with a large red marker and the coordinates
  displayed beside it.

In some places, it looks like Maps defaults to the nearest on-street location, but testing the click-on-the-link features does appear to go to the exact location.

Comment: Ah-HA! That's new. Was wondering when they'd finally make this possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure when it appeared, but was there when I looked yestereday.    There's one flaw:   if you choose a location that's not on-street, the display box shows the closest on-street address, and the exactly lat/long underneath it.    Most people will assume that these are for the same place, but that's not so.    Still - it's better than it was.

Comment: Now that I've used this more, I wish it would show the coordinates as actual lat/lon rather than degrees-minutes (oh well).

Answer (score 5):

The previous method no longer works, now you may get the coordinates from the URL. (Note: they are the coordinates of the place at the center of the window) Usually the URLs are like this -

```
https://www.google.co.in/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d788!2d88.4328534!3d22.6145349
```

or

```
https://www.google.co.in/maps/preview#!q=Statue+of+Liberty+National+Monument%2C+New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States&data=!1m4!1m3!1d2588!2d-74.0440104!3d40.6907415!4m11!1m10!2i15!4m8!1m3!1d3152!2d88.4379395!3d22.5734607!3m2!1i1366!2i657!4f13.1
```

Notice the `data` parameter -

```
data=!1m4!1m3!1d788!2d88.4328534!3d22.6145349
data=!1m4!1m3!1d2588!2d-74.0440104!3d40.6907415
```

Co-ordinates are clearly visible. For the first one `22.6145349, 88.4328534`, for the second one `40.6907415, -74.0440104`.

This might not be the best way to fetch coordinates from Google maps, but it's the only one as of now.

Comment: Looks like an easy chrome extension idea. Might end up building it this weekend if I am bored.

Comment: Note that those coordinates might not be those of the marker. They seem to point to where the map is centered. Note that, as you pan around, the coordinates in the URL gets updated.

Comment: Ah I missed to mention that. Yes, they are the coordinates of the place at the center of the window.

Answer (score 2):

I just created a tampermonkey script to help getting the coordinates from the new google maps:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Google maps coordinates fetcher
// @namespace  https://www.google.com/maps/preview
// @version    0.1
// @description  This script shows the current coordinates of the center of the map in the new google maps
// @match      https://www.google.com/maps/preview*
// @copyright  2013+, muddymind
// @require    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {


    //constants
    var SCRIPT_DEBUG_PREFIX = "Google maps coordinates fetcher: ";
    var DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

    var X_COORDINATE_INDENTIFIER = "!3d";
    var Y_COORDINATE_INDENTIFIER = "!2d";

    var COORDINATES_REFRESH_RATE = 1000;

    var DIV_CONTAINER_STYLE = "position: fixed; bottom: 20%; left: 0; background-color: white; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 10px; opacity: 0.6;";
    //end of constants

    //variables
    var coordinatesContainer = undefined;
    var previousCoordinateValue = "";
    //end of variables

    //auxiliar Classes and functions
    function util_consoleDebug(message, obj){
        if(DEBUG_ENABLED==true) {
            console.debug( SCRIPT_DEBUG_PREFIX + message );
        }

        if(obj!=undefined){
            console.debug( obj );
        }
    }

    function getParameter(parameterName){
        var url = window.location.href;

        var val = url.match(parameterName+"[0-9\.-]*");

        return val[0].substr(parameterName.length);
    }

    function updateCoordinates(){

        util_consoleDebug("updating coordinates...");

        try{

            var result = getParameter(X_COORDINATE_INDENTIFIER);
            result += ",";
            result += getParameter(Y_COORDINATE_INDENTIFIER);

            util_consoleDebug("current coordinates "+ result);

            if(previousCoordinateValue != result){
                coordinatesContainer.text(result);
                previousCoordinateValue = result;
                util_consoleDebug("coordinates updated to "+ result);
            }
            else{
                util_consoleDebug("no update needed!");
                //do nothing

            }

        }catch(Exception){
            util_consoleDebug("error updating coordinates - " + Exception);
        }

        util_consoleDebug("scheduling next update after " + COORDINATES_REFRESH_RATE);
        setTimeout(function(){updateCoordinates()}, COORDINATES_REFRESH_RATE);
    }
    //end of auxiliar Classes and functions


    //settings
    coordinatesContainer = $('<div style="' + DIV_CONTAINER_STYLE + '">');
    $('body').append(coordinatesContainer);    
    //end of settings

    //debug
    util_consoleDebug("script inited!");
    //end of debug


    //main
    updateCoordinates();
    //end of main
})()
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: this is very well done.

Answer (score 1):

Well just found this that might be helpfull as a tool so you can get coordinates in the form of lat,long

http://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use [this convertor](http://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can right click anywhere on the map and select "What's Here?" from the menu.  It will drop a green arrow.  Mouse over the green arrow to see a tool tip that contains the coordinates.  Click on the green arrow to see a pop-up window that also contains the coordinates.  You can copy the text from the pop-up window.

Comment: Nothing happens when you right-click on the new Google Maps.

Comment: +1: @Matt: Actually this works for me as of Nov 29, 2013 using firefox. I was about to post an answer and then saw this.  But for me, when I right click on the map and choose `What's Here?` the coordinates get pasted into the map search box at the top of the page.

Comment: @User Are you sure that's on the *new* Google Maps? Still nothing happens for me when I right-click...

Comment: @Matt: I'm not sure what you mean by "new" Google maps, but for example today I can go to `https://maps.google.com/` and either search for an address and do this or just start navigating on the map.  Either way when I right click and choose "What's here?" I get coordinates.  Also just tried this in IE and also worked.  Works whether I am logged into google or not.  Do you run an adblocker or some other addon that might interfere?

Comment: @Matt: Also just tried on Chrome and it also works for me.  This is all on Windows 7.

Comment: @User Does your Google Maps look like the first screenshot above or the second one?

Comment: @Matt: It looks like the first one so I guess we're talking about two different things.  I did a search for new google maps and came across google page that looks like your 2nd screenshot.  In this case when I left click it gives me the coordinates in the upper left corner albeit in degrees and minutes.

Comment: @Matt: good deal. The confusion for me was the term "new google maps" which I assumed was just the latest incarnation of whatever was at http://maps.google.com

Comment: Copy-pasting from the popup does not work anymore as of 2016.