# How to show a marker with a description at specific coordinates via URL with the new (mid-2013) Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, links

A link like this used to work up until the latest revamp of Google Maps (before July 2013):

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=description+(name)+%4046.090271,6.657248

What it did was to show a map with a pin placed at the provided lat/lng coordinates showing up with the given description text.

The plus of this "address format" was to place a pin "adjusted" exactly where you wanted it to be and still provide a meaningful description (like an address which would otherwise not be recognized and/or misplaced via a normal address-only search query).

Same goes for native mobile apps on iPhone/iPad and Android devices. It worked up until Google pushed the new native apps version out (before mid-July 2013), now it doesn't anymore.

Anyone knows if there is a workaround and/or a new or alternate format to obtain the same results with a single link?

Before anyone mentions JavaScript: I already know this can easily be accomplished via JS, but what I'm looking for here is a dead-simple basic link.

Also, I know just providing the coordinates with no description works, but I *do* need both the coordinates and the description (so basically something that behaves like it did before the update).

**EDIT**

Further clarification: Static Maps API would not work. I'm looking for a link that brings up the Google Maps Web Application.

**EDIT**

Just showing a marker at a given lat/lng is trivial (just ?q=lat,lng and you have it). What I want to accomplish is showing a marker ALONG WITH a description in the new google maps webapp.

Comment: ...just so you know, that link worked for me.

Comment: @A.M. must be using the old Google Maps then. I can confirm that in the new preview version of maps that the name doesn't show the same way.

Comment: So Google is serving up different versions for different places, maybe?  In that case, +1 to this question for trying to clear this up for me in advance, *from the future*.  Also, here is a related issue with the "new" (mid-2013) Google Maps: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45896/how-to-get-the-coordinates-in-the-new-google-maps?

Comment: @A.M. thanks, but that issue does not seem to be so closely related. It's really about a lab feature that was dropped with the "new" maps. Besides, the coordinates mentioned in the answer to that case are not really those of the marker, but those where the map is centered (the URL itself gets updated when you pan the map around)

Comment: do you want the description to be displayed in new maps?

Comment: @Sathya yes, I need the description to be displayed

Comment: @Sathya There are only 10 hours left for Sergio to be able to manually award a bounty.  It sounds like you were working on a solution, so if you have a more elegant answer than mine (and *any* answer probably would be!), then you should post it!

Comment: Is any way to force Google to serve me the "new" version you are using?  Again, the link in the question works just fine for me.  I don't even see how I can be using an old version of a web app.  If that's even possible, Google should make it more transparent.  For one thing, there is no version numbering visible.  In the meantime, I have a slight different link for you to try.  After (successfully) loading your link, I generated this with the link button:  https://maps.google.com/maps?q=description+(name)+%4046.090271,6.657248&t=m&z=15

Comment: @A.M. I couldn't figure out a way on the new Maps, so no ideas there

Comment: @A.M. to try out the "new" maps app you should just go to maps.google.com and in the left panel you should see a link like "Get the new google maps / try it now". If you can't see that, maybe Google didn't make it available in your country or region. You can try with a proxy (just be sure you're logged out of your gmail account) or maybe forcing the new link: https://www.google.com/maps/preview

Comment: @Sergio It works (as linked, without a proxy).  Thanks.  Now, whether I can test links to it I will have to find out...

Answer (score 1):

This format works for a specific location, though the label seems to be limited to 1 character:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.698217,-74.05&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:A%7C40.690217,-74.035&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.698217,-74.05&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3aorange%7Clabel%3aA%7C40.690217,-74.035&sensor=false)

If you *really* want to show more than one character, you can get around the limitation in a rough way by specifying more points:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.698217,-74.05&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3aorange%7Clabel%3aA%7C40.690217,-74.035&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aS%7C40.680217,-74.033&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aO%7C40.680217,-74.030&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aM%7C40.680217,-74.027&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aE%7C40.680217,-74.024&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aP%7C40.680217,-74.021&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aL%7C40.680217,-74.018&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aA%7C40.680217,-74.015&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aC%7C40.680217,-74.012&markers=color%3agray%7Clabel%3aE%7C40.680217,-74.009&sensor=false

You could actually spell out some long words this way, and according to Google, "Static Map URLs are restricted to 2048 characters in size", so you could generate a working link more than 3 times the size of the one just above and have fairly long "labels".

---

For the second example link, I just changed the first "label" letter to be at the edge of the frame south of the real point, gave every subsequent letter a small longitude change.  All of this could be done programmatically if you are trying to generate many of these (you would have to look at the center lat and long and the zoom level to get the latitude of "just inside the frame south of the real point").

I started with the example here, and then verified that you can give a latitude and longitude for the map centre as well as the marker, and that you can set the marker to somewhere not on a feature and have it show up exactly as specified:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example

(Note that the example given is for the Static Map version of Google Maps.  Long labels may be easier to create for other versions.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was asking about the google maps webapp, not the static maps API (I will add a clarification to my question)

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered the same issue with a slightly different URL that we use to show directions between a number of locations. This URL is now broken with or without descriptions:

```
http://www.maps.google.com?q=52.445365,0.619076+(Description1)+to:52.627721,1.282156+(Description2)+to:52.053842,1.146522+(Description3)
```

It seems you can do the same thing without descriptions in the new Google Maps, as follows:

```
http://www.google.com/maps/dir/52.245101,0.716032/52.445365,0.619076/52.627721,1.282156/52.053842,1.146
```

But the useful ability to give a location a description using only an URL seems to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/maps/place//@37.7,-122.4,16z/ seems to work - no description though.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not helpful. It's the same as invoking the URL in my question without the description: 
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=46.090271,6.657248

But the whole point of my question was for a way to get the description.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I've added a clarification to the original question to avoid further misunderstandings :)

Answer (score -2):

This should work if its a place that you're looking for:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/[[name]]/@[[lat]],[[lng]],15z
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. Perhaps you could include some examples in your answer?